# The correct approach to the authorization

Tags: html, session, language-agnostic, authorization

I need to remake one site. It has some pl and some html files. The problem is I don't know how to better make authorisation with this structure.
 Sure I Can check session var in every page, but it isn't very good, right? 
Another view is to try to load all the files throw one index file structure switch. Like this:

```
if ($authorised eq 'true') 
{
 switch($mode) {
  case 'one': { do "one.pl"; }
  case 'two': { do "two.pl"; }
  .....
  default : { print 'some went wrong'; }
 }
}
else
{
 do "login.pl";
}
```

Maybe there are any methods which would let me do what I want without checking authorisation in all files and without making structure like in 2nd suggestion.

Comment: Why is this tagged [php]?

Comment: You should not `require` or `do` Perl scripts into one another. That's really old and will get you in serious maintenance trouble. You might want to look at the web frameworks Dancer or Mojolicious, or consider Web::Simple (which is easier to deploy but harder to understand). If those are not an option, are you using CGI.pm and CGI::Session?

Comment: @Wooble why not? This is not PERL question, this is question about authorisation methods which are similar for perl and php.

Comment: @simbabque yes, I am using both.

Comment: Then why not get rid of the Perl code, rewrite in English, and tag language-agnostic? I see nothing whatsoever about PHP here.

Comment: What exactly are you now trying to achieve? Rewrite the Perl code in Perl or in PHP? I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @simbabque I just want to understand what approach to the authorization would be better for me. I don't need to rewrite perl code to php.

Comment: Basically yes, you need to check the session on every single request. That's the way it works. In order to not duplicate your checking code all over the place there are many approaches. A pretty good approach is to have exactly one entry point into the app, in which you do all the checking first, and then *route* to other controllers/modules/functions based on the requested URL. Look into *routing* for this. That's not the only valid approach though and explaining it in full is probably beyond the scope of a single answer.

Comment: @deceze, well its the 2nd method. Okay, thank you.

Comment: @simbabque I am going to use Web::Simpe on my site. [link](http://search.cpan.org/~mstrout/Web-Simple-0.020/lib/Web/Simple.pm#Examples) Is there any example showing how Web-Spell works. I have few questions, but they may contain code, don't think its a good idea to post it here

Answer (score 2):

> Sure I Can check session var in every page, but it isn't very good, right?

In terms of mechanics, that's exactly what you're supposed to do. Check the session for every page that needs authorization. Weather or not you code is good or bad depends on how you do it.

Generally, by "bad code" most programmers mean code that increases the tendency to make a mistake. Duplicated code for example have a tendency to force you to do search-and-replace programming when fixing bugs or modifying code. So if in each page you're doing something like:

```
if ( session.auth ) {
    render_page();
}
else {
    redirect_to_login();
}
```

Then yes, that's indeed bad coding.

*(Note that the code above and all the following code is pseudocode borrowing syntax from various languages to present the idea with minimal noise)*

What most people tend to do is factor out the authorization code into a module, library or class and use it for each page. So the module may look something like:

```
class Auth {
    static function init (session) {
        if ( ! session.auth ) redirect_to_login();
    }
}
```

And at the top of each page you'd do something like:

```
require Auth::init(session);
```

Some frameworks get a bit more fancy and do the authorization in a dispatcher. You basically write all your controllers and views as if there is no authorization but in the dispatcher you label specific pages that require authorization:

```
App.dispatch({
    '/' : 'Index',
    '/login' : 'Login',
    '/mail' : {
        controller : 'Mail',
        auth : true // requires authorization
    },
    '/send' : {
        controller : 'Mail',
        command : 'send',
        auth : true
    }
});
```

Some frameworks do the opposite, assuming that auth is required unless explicitly disabled:

```
App.dispatch({
    '/' : {
        controller : 'Index',
        noauth : true
    },
    '/login' : {
        controller 'Login',
        noauth : true
    },
    '/mail' : 'Mail',
    '/send' : 'Mail.send'
});
```

In some languages, frameworks can get fancier. Perl for example allows you to attach attributes to functions so that you can basically tag a function to indicate that it requires authorization. So you can basically write code that looks something like this:

```
function index :web () {
    return render('index.html');
}

function mail :web :auth (query) {
    return render('mail.html', mail.fetch(query.page||0));
}
```

Another alternative for frameworks without dispatchers (or with auto dispatch) is to declare a list of pages that requires authorization at the top of the module/class:

```
class MailController inherits WebApp::Controller {
    require_auth = [ 'index', 'send' ];

    function index () {
        return render('mail.html');
    }

    function send (query) {
        new Mail.send(query.to,query.body);
        return render('sent.html');
    }
}
```